# CakePHP Router::connect() config, custom parameter parsing

Tags: regex, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, router

I've got the following routes.php configuration

```
Router::connect('/:type/:slug;:id', array(
        'controller' => 'content',
        'action' => 'show',
        'type' => null,
        'slug' => null,
        'id' => null,
    ),
    array(
        'type' => '(articles|releases|answers|videos)',
        'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+',
        'id' => '[0-9]+',
        'pass' => array('type', 'slug', 'id'),
    ));
```

and I'm trying to parse the following URL:

```
/answers/effective-language-therapy-for-people;368
```

And the router is getting me to the correct controller & action, but dumping `$this->params` shows me that it's not correctly identifying the `$id` and the `$slug`

```
Array
(
    [type] => answers
    [slug] => answers
    [id] => effective-language-therapy-for-people
    [named] => Array
        (
        )

    [pass] => Array
        (
            [0] => answers
            [1] => answers
            [2] => effective-language-therapy-for-people
        )

    [controller] => content
    [action] => show
    [plugin] => 
    [url] => Array
        (
            [ext] => html
            [url] => answers/effective-language-therapy-for-people;368
        )

    [form] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

So - what gives?  is my regex wrong, approach missing something, or what?  Any ideas?

Note: I have read:

- http://book.cakephp.org/view/948/Defining-Routes
- http://book.cakephp.org/view/949/Passing-parameters-to-action

---

UPDATE, resolved and working version

```
Router::connect('/:type/:slug:splitter:id', array('controller' => 'content', 'action' => 'view',), array(
    'type' => 'articles|releases|answers|videos',
    'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+',
    'splitter' => '[\;\-\|]+',
    'id' => '[0-9]+',
    ));
```

Comment: I don't like the look of the semicolon between the slug and the number.

Comment: understood, it could be a dash or anything else for all I care, but I was reducing the number of possible issues for this test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
Router::connect('/:type/:slug;:id', array(
    'controller' => 'content',
    'action' => 'show',
    'type' => null,
    'slug' => null,
    'id' => null,
),
array(
    'type' => 'articles|releases|answers|videos',
    'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+',
    'id' => '[0-9]+',
    'pass' => array('type', 'slug', 'id'),
));
```

The problem was types in parenthesis `()` which is not supported in CakePHP.

Comment: That was it, changed the code to:

 Router::connect('/:type/:slug:splitter:id', array('controller' => 'content', 'action' => 'view',), array(
  'type' => 'articles|releases|answers|videos',
  'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+',
  'splitter' => '[\;\-\|]+',
  'id' => '[0-9]+',
  ));